# Spring Boot + Spring Security + Tomcat = No visible WebSecurityExpressionHandler instance could be found in the application context

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-security, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I get this error quite often when deploying war application to Tomcat:

> No visible WebSecurityExpressionHandler instance could be found in the
>   application context.

What helps is to stop and reload the app in tomcat manager application (once, twice, sometimes more but reload always helps at some point).

Yet this never happen when I run the app as jar.

What should I do to have a reliable tomcat deployment process? Right now it's like: upload, start, check, not working so stop, start, check not working so stop, start, ok works.

EDIT:

- Spring Boot  1.2.3 Release
- Thymeleaf 2.1.4-Release
- Tomcat 7
- Java 8

```java
42095 [http-bio-80-exec-1] INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[.[.pl].[/##1.0.3] - Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet' 
42095 [http-bio-80-exec-1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started 
42183 [http-bio-80-exec-1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 88 ms 
43463 [http-bio-80-exec-1] ERROR org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine - [THYMELEAF][http-bio-80-exec-1] Exception processing template "index": No visible WebSecurityExpressionHandler instance could be found in the application context. There must be at least one in order to support expressions in Spring Security authorization queries. (fragments/page_elements) 
43483 [http-bio-80-exec-1] ERROR o.s.b.context.web.ErrorPageFilter - Forwarding to error page from request [/] due to exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: No visible WebSecurityExpressionHandler instance could be found in the application context. There must be at least one in order to support expressions in Spring Security authorization queries. (fragments/page_elements)] 
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: No visible WebSecurityExpressionHandler instance could be found in the application context. There must be at least one in order to support expressions in Spring Security authorization queries. (fragments/page_elements)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620) ~[tomcat-servlet-api-3.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) ~[tomcat-servlet-api-3.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:139) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:113) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:88) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040) [tomcat-coyote-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607) [tomcat-coyote-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313) [tomcat-coyote-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_40]
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: No visible WebSecurityExpressionHandler instance could be found in the application context. There must be at least one in order to support expressions in Spring Security authorization queries. (fragments/page_elements)
    at org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity3.auth.AuthUtils.getExpressionHandler(AuthUtils.java:267) ~[thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity3.auth.AuthUtils.authorizeUsingAccessExpression(AuthUtils.java:182) ~[thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity3.dialect.processor.AuthorizeAttrProcessor.isVisible(AuthorizeAttrProcessor.java:100) ~[thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractConditionalVisibilityAttrProcessor.processAttribute(AbstractConditionalVisibilityAttrProcessor.java:59) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractAttrProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttrProcessor.java:87) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.AbstractProcessor.process(AbstractProcessor.java:212) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.applyNextProcessor(Node.java:1017) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:972) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Document.process(Document.java:93) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1155) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 69 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete stack trace? What versions of Spring Boot, Spring Security, and Thymeleaf are you using?

Comment: I'm using Spring Boot 1.2.3 Release and Spring Security (and Thymeleaf) version is managed by spring boot starter pom (I'm not overriding spring security version in my pom.xml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do have the same error with

- Spring Boot 1.3.x, 1.4.x -> creating war file
- Thymeleaf 2.1.5 (+ thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4-2.1.2.RELEASE)
- Tomcat 8 (tested until 8.0.36)
- Java 8

**The reason:**
Spring Boot is creating two application contexts, one WebApplicationContext with Tomcat listeners etc. and another WebApplicationContext with all your beans. Furthermore the second context is set as parent to first context.
Unfortunately Thymeleaf AuthUtils will get the first context, where they try to resolve the WebSecurityExpressionHandler bean, but the bean resolvement is not checking the parent context. (I don't know if this is a bug in bean resolvement in AuthUtils of Thymeleaf or if it's a Bug in Spring...)

Nevertheless I don't have a correct solution for that right now - just a workaround.

**Workaround:**
I could resolve this problem by deleting the folder contents:

- /tomcat/work/<web-context>/*
- /tomcat/temp/*

But I figured out that this workaround doesn't work for

- Tomcat 8.0.41
- Tomcat 8.5.11

**Edit:**
I could solve problem, but for me it was some kind of misconfiguration.

First of all you should read this: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html

There is also mentioned that:

> If your existing application has more than one ApplicationContext (e.g. if it uses AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer) then you might be able to squash all your context sources into a single SpringApplication

But in my case, I had a second class extending the SpringBootServletInitializer which contained beans for servlet registration. Overriding the "configure" method intensified the problem. Removing this extension from this class solved the problem.

Comment: I accepted your answer because you gave the reason, but I solved my problem by calculating user's security attributes in controller and passed them to thymeleaf as flags.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a bean from the class `org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler` will solve your issue

**But as you are using `Spring-boot`**

Please check you have included the following libraries to your `gradle` or `maven`. *(the below format is of gradle)*

1. `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf`
2. `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web`
3. `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security`
4. `org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3:2.1.1.RELEASE`